# Flutter how to add search function in listview builder

Tags: flutter

I am migrating my app from ionic to Flutter and stuck at search function. I need to add simple search bar in the ListViewbuilder but don't know how.

MY code is

```
class _HospitallistState extends State<Hospitallist> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    doSomeAsyncStuff();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List> doSomeAsyncStuff() async {
    String url2 =
        'http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_igitakaful/insurance-api/get_panel_hospitals.php?offset=0&limit=1000';

    final response2 = await http.get(url2);
    var Data = json.decode(response2.body);
    print(Data["records"]);
    return Data["records"];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('IGI GENERAL INSURANCE'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List>(
          future: doSomeAsyncStuff(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    child: Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new RichText(
                              text: new TextSpan(
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                children: <TextSpan>[
                                  new TextSpan(text: 'Name' + ' ' + ':' + ' '),
                                  new TextSpan(
                                      text: snapshot.data[index]['name'],
                                      style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Colors.blue)),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text('Address : ' +
                                ' ' +
                                snapshot.data[index]['address'])
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

I hear there is some builtin function in listview builder from which we can add search option maybe ? Not sure, Or if any other way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple [blog](https://blog.usejournal.com/flutter-search-in-listview-1ffa40956685). You can check the following code:

```
  
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'ListView with Search'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();

  final duplicateItems = List<String>.generate(10000, (i) => "Item $i");
  var items = List<String>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    items.addAll(duplicateItems);
    super.initState();
  }

  void filterSearchResults(String query) {
    List<String> dummySearchList = List<String>();
    dummySearchList.addAll(duplicateItems);
    if(query.isNotEmpty) {
      List<String> dummyListData = List<String>();
      dummySearchList.forEach((item) {
        if(item.contains(query)) {
          dummyListData.add(item);
        }
      });
      setState(() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(dummyListData);
      });
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(duplicateItems);
      });
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  filterSearchResults(value);
                },
                controller: editingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Search",
                    hintText: "Search",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('${items[index]}'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```